# Show that $a<b$ iff $a^n<b^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

At first I thought it was obvious, but one implication is giving me a hard time. I would appreciate if one the implications demonstrated were to be revised as well help or hints with the other implication.

I have to prove for $a,b\in \mathbb Q^+$ that $a<b \Leftrightarrow a^n<b^n$ with $n\in\mathbb N$. For the right implication "$\Rightarrow$", by induction for $n=1$ we have that $a<b \Rightarrow a^1<b^1 \Rightarrow a<b$

Now, suppose that $a<b\Rightarrow a^n<b^n$, this would be our induction hypothesis. We have to prove that $a<b\Rightarrow a^{n+1} <b^{n+1}$

Then, $a<b\Rightarrow a^n<b^n \Rightarrow a^na<b^na \Rightarrow a^{n+1}<b^n a$

We also have that $a<b\Rightarrow ab^n<bb^n\Rightarrow ab^n<b^{n+1}$

Now, $a^{n+1}<ab^n<b^{n+1} \Rightarrow a^{n+1}<b^{n+1}$

$\therefore a<b\Rightarrow a^n<b^n$

For the left implication "$\Leftarrow$" we have to prove that $a^n<b^n\Rightarrow a<b$. Suppose $m,k,r,s\in \mathbb Z$, $k\neq 0, s\neq 0$ and $a,b\in\mathbb Q^+$ such that $$a={ m\over k} , b={r\over s}$$
So $a^n<b^n \Rightarrow ({m \over k})^n<({r\over s})^n\Rightarrow {m^n \over k^n}<{r^n \over s^n} \Rightarrow m^ns^n<k^nr^n \Rightarrow (ms)^n<(kr)^n$. To this point I would have to prove that, for $a,b\in \mathbb Z^+$ and $n\in \mathbb N, a<b \Leftrightarrow a^n<b^n$ to say that $(ms)^n<(kr)^n\Rightarrow ms<kr$. The demonstration of the right implication "$\Rightarrow$" is almost identical to the first one but I still don't know how to prove the left implication "$\Leftarrow$" for integers.

Comment: I hope $a>0$ is also part of the question. Otherwise, let $a=-2$ and $b=-1$ or $b=1$. Then $a^2 = 4 > 1 = b^2$ and we have a contradiction.

Comment: It says $a,b\in\mathbb Q^+$.

Comment: Yes, $a,b \in \mathbb Q^+$

Comment: To both of you, thanks. I missed that when skimming the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one of the few cases you'll ever find where proving one implication gives you a proof for both.

You have proven that $a<b\ \implies a^n<b^n$. Now you want to prove $a^n<b^n\ \implies a<b$. But you can look at the contrapositive: $a\not<b\ \implies a^n\not< b^n$; that is, 
$$
b\leq a\ \implies \ b^n\leq a^n. 
$$
If $b=a$, then $b^n=a^n$. If $b<a$, then $b^n<a^n$ by the first implication.

Comment: Very nice, I didn't see the contrapositive. This would work with both the demonstration with integers and rationals. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are very welcome. This is a tricky example that we sometimes teach in "proofs" classes, and it is usually hard for the students.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

$$0<(b^n-a^n)= (b-a)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots +ab^{n-2}+b^n).$$